# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'ITnews$default.auth_user' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, django, django-models

when I do:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'ITnews$default.auth_user' doesn't exist")
```

I trying to deploy my website in pythonanywhere. And I cannot to connect site and mysql.

Database settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'ITnews$default',
    'USER': 'ITnews',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
    'HOST': 'ITnews.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
}
```

}
:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be sure to run `python manage.py makemigrations` first, then use `migrate`.
Note that if you do not have a customized User model, you must have the following app in your settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
)
```

Comment: 1) I tried to do "python manage.py makemigrations" and "python manage.py migrate", and i het error. 2) this is my list of apps: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'debug_toolbar',
    "ckeditor",
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'captcha',
] (sorry for my english. I'm from Ukraine)

Comment: We can't help you debug an error if you do not tell us what the error is.